# Fetching the id of an anchor Link tag on a form and submit to backend

Tags: javascript, forms, anchor

Am working on a project which has a form and inside the form there is an anchor link tag with a dynamic id.Am using the anchor link tag to submit the form via Javascript. I want to fetch the id of the **same anchor link tag** (which is dynamic) and submit to the backend but cant figure out how to fetch it..

**The form**

```
<form method="POST" action="#" id="rsmForm">
    <!-- Token field-->
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">  

     <a href="#demo{{$i}}" id="{{ $a['id'] }}" name="asmID" data-value="{{ $a['id'] }}" onclick="document.getElementById('rsmForm').submit();"> + ASM ({{ $a['id'] }}) </a>
</form>
```

Comment: you can get the id of clicked link using Jquery ($(this).attr('id')).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onclick` callback, get the href attribute value of the anchor:

```js
function onClickAnchor(e) {
  const currentHref = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('href');
  console.log(currentHref);
  // document.getElementById('rsmForm').submit();  <=== uncomment it
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="#" id="rsmForm">
    <!-- Token field-->
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">  

     <a href="#demo{{$i}}" id="{{ $a['id'] }}" name="asmID" data-value="{{ $a['id'] }}" onclick="onClickAnchor(event)"> + ASM ({{ $a['id'] }}) </a>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks,, your suggestion works but am submitting the form to the backend via POST (to PHP) .. Am looking for idea where I can fetch the values (and submit to the backend) directly.

Comment: what do you mean? that you want to send this retrieved value value to PHP? or what?

Comment: Yah,, so that when I dd() on the backend I get the values

Comment: but you mean all the values of your form? or just the anchor you just retrieved?

Comment: but in this case why you don't structure your HTML in order to have directly the `href` value as `action` attribute of the form? Did you try it?

Comment: Basically the action of the form redirects to a different path, I want on click of the anchor tag (I get the id of the anchor together with the token) and submit to the backend..

Comment: so you must ajax for it

Comment: Okay,, so I Cant fetch the id of the anchor link tag and post direclty to the backend..